# Find all classes that implement a given protocol in XCode4

Tags: iphone, xcode4

Is there an easy way in XCode 4, to find all the classes that implement a given protocol?

This looks like a pretty common scenario, but I couldn't find how to do it... The only solution I've found is searching (textual search) for the protocol name in the entire project, but of course the number of results is much grater than what I need.

Comment: Why it is much greater? It should be in common case NUMBER_OF_CLASSES_THAT_IMPLEMENT + 1...

Comment: Nekto: because the search results also show all the instance variables and methods that USE the protocol...

Comment: This SO question has a couple of answers that show ways to do it in code: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9882984/203673 I'm hoping someone else can answer this with a way to do it inside the IDE though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get list of all classes conform to certain protocol in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882984/how-do-i-get-list-of-all-classes-conform-to-certain-protocol-in-xcode-4)

Comment: Although this was asked first, voting to close as a duplicate because the later question has an accepted answer.