# How do I get list of all classes conform to certain protocol in Xcode 4?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I am new to Xcode. I want to know how can I know all classes conform to certain protocol in Xcode 4.3.1?
And how can I know all subclasses of one class?

Comment: Sad that even in 2020 with Xcode 12.2, this is still unavailable. On the other hand, AppCode from JetBrains has had this years. https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/download/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the [Objective-C runtime functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418).

- `objc_getClassList` to get the list of `Class`es
- `class_getSuperclass` or the `-superclass` method to walk the superclass chain
- `class_conformsToProtocol` or the `-conformsToProtocol:` method to check if a class conforms to a protocol

Comment: fwiw, `class_conformsToProtocol` is WAY faster than `-conformsToProtocol`. This is quite a bottle neck in a large app with thousands of classes

Answer (score 8):

```
Protocol *protocol = @protocol(YourProtocol);

int numberOfClasses = objc_getClassList(NULL, 0);
Class *classList = malloc(numberOfClasses * sizeof(Class));
numberOfClasses = objc_getClassList(classList, numberOfClasses);

for (int idx = 0; idx < numberOfClasses; idx++) 
{
    Class class = classList[idx];
    if (class_getClassMethod(class, @selector(conformsToProtocol:)) && [class conformsToProtocol:protocol])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass(class));
    }
}
free(classList);
```

Comment: I'm new to ObjC programming, but know C well. Do you see any potential problems doing Class classList[numberOfClasses]; instead of malloc+free?

Comment: @Tommy Well, you're right, that would be faster to allocate memory on the stack

Comment: also less things that can go wrong, which is almost always better.